# Erron in Gitlab-runner kubernetes | Job failed (system failure):

Tags: kubernetes, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

I'm using gitlab CI pipeline and setup my own kubernetes gitlab runner successfully. But when I run a job in that runner, it gives the following error.

```
ERROR: Job failed (system failure): prepare environment: setting up credentials: Unauthorized. Check https://docs.gitlab.com/runner/shells/index.html#shell-profile-loading for more information
```

I was using only token when creating a gitlab-runner, please assist me to resolve this issue.

for more info, screenshot attached here.
[image]

Thanks.

Comment: Please provide information about your system.

Comment: it's deployed in kubernetes using gitlab runner official repo. Only token has been passed.
helm install --namespace gitlab-runner --name demo-runner -f values.yaml gitlab/gitlab-runner